# How can develop Windows C# App using BLE

Tags: c#, bluetooth, msdn, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to develop a windows app that communicate with bluetooth device.

Now I have one bluetooth-usb dongle for my windows desktop and bluetooth BLE device.

I want to develop the app using C# and Visual Studio in Windows 10.
But I can't find official documents and APIs at all. There's no C# API about BLE in windows? If it is, How can I develop a C# App using BLE?

Comment: I'm in a similar position, and am finding lack of good documentation/examples a real problem.

If you are using Windows 10 and VS2015 you should have access to the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice namespace, I would start there.

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft Bluetooth team did a Build talk which includes BLE sample apps for GATT Server, Beacons, and Pairing. You can find the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/kpathakota/Build2016BluetoothCodeSamples).

A Build talk about Beacons and reading from a GATT Server can be found [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P416).

Comment: Good info. Just a note that this talk and demo is for UWP

Answer (score 1):

There is a BLE example included in the Universal Windows sample programs provided by Microsoft.  It is called BluetoothGattHeartRate.

Not that this is the end all, but it does get you going.  It would be nice, given the whole IOT push if they had a Windows Bluetooth developer example that made configuring, and all the features really simple...